# How to fix a list comprehensions with nested for loop and IF AND statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension

To reduce the computation time of these for loops + if/else statement, I try to create a list comprehension. However it is not working quite as I expected.

The result should be a list of length 15, thus not including any t values (0,1,2) for X and W.

The following works:

```
c = ["X", "Y"]
l = ["Z", "Q", "W"]
t = [0,1,2]
index = 0

for i in c:
    for j in l:
        for k in t:
            if i == "X" and j == "W":
                index = index
            else:
                state[index] = len(Data_frame.loc[(Data_frame["ColunmName1"] == i) & (Data_frame["ColunmName2"] == j) & (Data_frame["ColunmName3"] == k)]) 
                index += 1
```

I have tried to convert it to a list comprehension in the following way, which is not working:

```
state = [len(current_orderlist.loc[(Data_frame["ColunmName1"]  == i) & Data_frame["ColunmName2"] == j) & (Data_frame["ColunmName3"]  == k)])  for i in c for j in l for k in if i != "X" and j != "W"]
```

Result:

```
state = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: A list comprehension will not change the Big-O complexity of an algorithm. Three for loops are three for loops whether you put them inside or outside square brackets.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You are totally right, but the way Python is implemented, list comprehension is slightly more efficient than nested `for` blocks. It's a measly improvement though if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

c = ["X", "Y"]
l = ["Z", "Q", "W"]
t = [0, 1, 2]
index = 0
```

### using itertools.product:

```
[x for x in product(c, l, t)]
```

#### output of all combinations:

```
[('X', 'Z', 0),
 ('X', 'Z', 1),
 ('X', 'Z', 2),
 ('X', 'Q', 0),
 ('X', 'Q', 1),
 ('X', 'Q', 2),
 ('X', 'W', 0),
 ('X', 'W', 1),
 ('X', 'W', 2),
 ('Y', 'Z', 0),
 ('Y', 'Z', 1),
 ('Y', 'Z', 2),
 ('Y', 'Q', 0),
 ('Y', 'Q', 1),
 ('Y', 'Q', 2),
 ('Y', 'W', 0),
 ('Y', 'W', 1),
 ('Y', 'W', 2)]
```

### your loop:

```
for i, j, k in product(c, l, t):
    if i == "X" and j == "W":
        index = index
    else:
        print(index, i, j, k)
        index+=1
```

### your loop with `list comprehension`:

```
[[i, j, k] for i, j, k in product(c, l, t) if (i, j) != ('X', 'W')]
```

#### output of `list comprehension`:

```
[['X', 'Z', 0],
 ['X', 'Z', 1],
 ['X', 'Z', 2],
 ['X', 'Q', 0],
 ['X', 'Q', 1],
 ['X', 'Q', 2],
 ['Y', 'Z', 0],
 ['Y', 'Z', 1],
 ['Y', 'Z', 2],
 ['Y', 'Q', 0],
 ['Y', 'Q', 1],
 ['Y', 'Q', 2],
 ['Y', 'W', 0],
 ['Y', 'W', 1],
 ['Y', 'W', 2]]
```

- The `DataFrame` isn't available so I didn't attempt to recreate it